# Find a minimal polynomial of element

Tags: number-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ be a root of polynomial $z^3+z+3$

How can I find a minimal polynomial of $\alpha - \alpha^2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Let $A$ be a matrix with characteristic polynomial $z^3+z+3$. Find the characteristic polynomial of $A-A^2$.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to set $y=z-z^2$ and eliminate $z$ using $z^3+z+3=0$.

Note: The first equation enables you to reduce the second to an expression linear in $z$. Then express $z$ in terms of $y$ and feed into the first equation.